# AWS programatic credential use in automation scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services

Right now we create scripts that run through CLI to automate or fetch things from AWS.

But we used AWS access key/ secret access/session token for the same.

these keys and tokens are valid for 1 hour.  Hence next hour if we do use them, the script will fail.

But it is also not possible to fetch the temp credentials, update the script, and run those.

So what is the best possible solution in this condition?  What should I do that I can get the updated credentials and I can run the script by using those updated credentials (automatically)?  Or any other alternatives so that we can still run scripts from our local machines using Boto with AWS credentials?

any help is appreciated.

Bhavesh

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your script runs outside of AWS, otherwise you would simply configure your compute (EC2, Lambda, etc.) to automatically assume an IAM role.

If you have persistent IAM User credentials that allow you to assume the relevant role then use those.

If you don't then take a look at the new [IAM Roles Anywhere](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/07/aws-identity-access-management-iam-roles-anywhere-workloads-outside-aws/) feature.

Comment: Only issue is for IAM roles anywhere, we need to get a ceritficate, which is to be used in all the machines that we will consume for automation.      Is there any other alternate to just generate and use the temp credentials (Other then root user)?

Comment: To use STS to generate temporary AWS credentials, you need a way to authenticate to AWS. IAM Roles Anywhere or IAM User credentials are two options. You should [never](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#lock-away-credentials) be using the root user for this.